# vis.js: How to expand/collapse nodes with mouse click

Tags: javascript, chap-links-library

just playing around with [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) for a day now and been through all the docs and examples. I'm trying to figure out the best way to refresh my node and edge data with click events. E.g. say I have one node with no edges, then I click it to add 3 child nodes. Could a vis.js expert suggest best way to do this?

Expected Before:

```
nodes = [{id: 1,   label:"Parent Node"} ];
edges = [ ];
```

Expected After click on id 1:

```
nodes = [{id: 1,   label:"Parent Node"},
{id: 2,   label:"Child Node1"},
{id: 3,   label:"Child Node2"},
{id: 4,   label:"Child Node3"} ];
edges = [ {from: 1, to: 2},
          {from: 1, to: 3},
          {from: 1, to: 4} ];
```

Then I'd want to collapse and go back to just the parent node w/ no children. I get how to do the event handling, it's the updating and redrawing of the nodes and edges I'm not sure about.

Comment: have you found any way to do this.Need help!

Answer (score 5):

Once I posted I figured out my mistake, not using the dynamic [DataSet()](http://visjs.org/docs/dataset.html).
So it should be like this:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([{id: 1,   label:"Parent Node"}]);
var edges = new vis.DataSet([]);
```

Then you can update like so:

```
nodes.update({id: 2,   label:"Child Node1"});
nodes.update({id: 3,   label:"Child Node2"});
nodes.update({id: 4,   label:"Child Node3"});

edges.update({from: 1, to: 2});
edges.update({from: 1, to: 3});
edges.update({from: 1, to: 4});
```

Comment: How are you collapsing the node ? Removing from network / hiding or something else ?

Comment: @RohitTotala This is pretty old, I don't recall. I wound up switching to D3 instead, it wound up being much easier to work with.

Comment: Okay, I did it by making a recursive call updating(hiding) child nodes & edges in network. I'll make a fiddle for SO over this weekend. Thanks. 
D3 has good options for Hierarchical networks/trees I guess.

Comment: @rhitz how's it going with the fiddle from 2017?